# What are the standard setting for swapiness etc? Constant crashing currently

Tags: 20.04, kernel, crash

My ubuntu 20.04.2 machine is constantly crashing whenever I use more than a small amount of RAM.  If I for example have a Jupyter notebook open in chrome and do some CPU intensive computation the whole system will often freeze completely so I can't even move the mouse. I can "fix it" using Alt-sysrq-f but this is really not ideal.

It seems it might be the OOM killer that is causing the problem. What are the standard settings (swapiness etc) for a 16GB linux box so I can just copy them and see if that fixes things?  It is currently driving me crazy.

```
free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           13Gi       3.0Gi       7.9Gi       119Mi       2.8Gi        10Gi
Swap:         2.0Gi          0B       2.0Gi


sysctl vm.swappiness
vm.swappiness = 10


grep -i swap /etc/fstab
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0


ls -la /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/
total 20
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 Apr 23  2020 .
drwxr-xr-x 7 root root 4096 Mar 26 09:01 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Aug 14  2020 desktop-icons@csoriano
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Dec 17 09:28 ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Nov 24 12:06 ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com


ls -la /var/crash
total 66968
drwxrwsrwt  2 root     whoopsie     4096 Mar 31 18:51 .
drwxr-xr-x 14 root     root         4096 Apr 23  2020 ..
-rw-r-----  1 user     whoopsie 68556347 Mar 31 18:51 _usr_share_teams_teams.1000.crash
-rw-r--r--  1 user     whoopsie        0 Mar 31 18:51 _usr_share_teams_teams.1000.upload
-rw-------  1 whoopsie whoopsie       37 Mar 31 18:51 _usr_share_teams_teams.1000.uploaded
```

Output of `top`

```
top - 16:55:35 up 1 min,  1 user,  load average: 2.35, 0.79, 0.28
Tasks: 364 total,   3 running, 361 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  5.4 us,  1.1 sy,  0.0 ni, 90.9 id,  2.1 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.5 si,  0.0 st
MiB Mem :  13939.7 total,   9030.9 free,   2293.8 used,   2615.0 buff/cache
MiB Swap:   4096.0 total,   4096.0 free,      0.0 used.  11294.8 avail Mem 

    PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND  
   4035 user      20   0 6268860 205524 110728 S  24.2   1.4   0:05.56 skypefo+ 
   3579 user      20   0  826360 233764 152592 S   5.3   1.6   0:04.88 chrome   
   1630 user      20   0 5359780 307316 118844 S   4.3   2.2   0:08.09 gnome-s+ 
   4116 user      20   0 5626104 113272  91952 S   4.3   0.8   0:00.56 skypefo+ 
   3618 user      20   0  649480 137168  91180 S   4.0   1.0   0:02.42 chrome   
   1299 user      20   0 1433488  90628  56156 S   2.6   0.6   0:02.52 Xorg     
   3834 user      20   0   36.4g 142796  88768 S   2.3   1.0   0:04.01 chrome   
   3877 user      20   0 2200908 115344  79896 S   2.3   0.8   0:07.09 skypefo+ 
   2258 user      20   0 2747244 134668  94496 S   1.3   0.9   0:01.39 teams    
   2401 user      20   0 2741456 414736 115904 S   1.3   2.9   0:18.69 teams    
   4045 user      20   0  816792  53108  40540 R   0.7   0.4   0:00.55 gnome-t+ 
     65 root      20   0       0      0      0 I   0.3   0.0   0:00.16 kworker+ 
    240 root      20   0       0      0      0 I   0.3   0.0   0:00.23 kworker+ 
    241 root      20   0       0      0      0 I   0.3   0.0   0:00.13 kworker+ 
    663 root      -2   0       0      0      0 S   0.3   0.0   0:00.55 gfx      
   1106 root      20   0  335928  19916  16752 S   0.3   0.1   0:01.09 Network+ 
   4087 user      20   0   12160   4032   3268 R   0.3   0.0   0:00.04 top
```

`sudo lshw -C memory` gives https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/4jS9HFBqN3/

Comment: @Terrance I already have vm.swappiness=10 in /etc/sysctl.conf. What else can I configure that might  help?

Comment: Edit your question and show me `free -h` and `sysctl vm.swappiness` and `grep -i swap /etc/fstab` and `ls -al /var/crash` and `top`.

Comment: And `ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions` and `ls -al /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions`.

Comment: You might also want to run a check on your memory chips (i.e., `memtest`).

Comment: @heynnema I don't have ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions and I am not sure how to show you "top".  The freezes don't show in /var/crash it seems but I do get messages in dmesg once the OOM killer eventually kicks in.

Comment: Use the `top` command, copy the output to the clipboard, edit your question, and paste the clipboard in, select the pasted text, then click the {} icon to format it. Your vm.swappiness may be too low. 13G is an odd amount of RAM. Show me `sudo lshw -C memory`.

Comment: Without knowing the hardware you have, I would assume that the missing 3GiB is shared with video memory.  It is quite common with onboard video cards.

Comment: @Terrance What hardware info can I provide? I have an  AMD Ryzen 5 3400G with Radeon Vega Graphics .

Comment: AMD Ryzen processors are notorious for RAM compatibility issues.

Comment: @Anush I bet that the 3GiB is shared between RAM and the Vega which is showing as built in to the CPU.  I am not familiar enough with the Jupyter Notebook to know how it operates but I do know that Chrome can be a massive memory hog. This is one of the reasons I try to avoid Chrome as much as possible. Is is possible to maybe run the Jupyter Notebook from Firefox?  This is only guessing since I have never used it before and don't want to write an answer based on guesses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**swap**

Your /swapfile may be too small. Let's change it from 2G to 4G and see if that helps...

**Note**: Incorrect use of the `dd` command can cause data loss. Suggest copy/paste.

In the `terminal`...

```
sudo swapoff -a           # turn off swap
sudo rm -i /swapfile      # remove old /swapfile

sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1M count=4096

sudo chmod 600 /swapfile  # set proper file protections
sudo mkswap /swapfile     # init /swapfile
sudo swapon /swapfile     # turn on swap
free -h                   # confirm 16G RAM and 4G swap
```

<strike>Edit /etc/fstab, using `sudo -H gedit /etc/fstab` or `sudo pico /etc/fstab`.</strike>

Confirm this /swapfile line in /etc/fstab... and confirm no other “swap” lines... use SPACES in this line... confirm NO TABS...

```
/swapfile  none  swap  sw  0  0
```

---

```
reboot                    # reboot and verify operation
```

**memtest**

Go to https://www.memtest86.com/ and download/run their free `memtest` to test your memory. Get at least one complete pass of all the 4/4 tests to confirm good memory. This may take many hours to complete.

**Note**: vm.swappiness=10 may be too low (60 is default), and 13G RAM is an odd amount. Let's review `sudo lshw -C memory`. We may modify vm.swappiness later.

**Update #1:**

**Memory**

Your memory may be installed incorrectly, and/or you may have a defective DIMM, as you have two 8G DIMMS, but only show 13G RAM, and both DIMMS show up in DIMM1 memory slots.

**Note**: AMD Ryzen processors are notorious for RAM compatibility issues.

Review the User Manual for your PC/motherboard, and confirm that you have the memory installed into the correct slots for memory interleaving. Re-seat the DIMMS if possible.

**Update #2:**

**BIOS**

Gigabyte A320M-S2H

Rev 1 https://www.gigabyte.com/us/Motherboard/GA-A320M-S2H-rev-1x#kf

Rev 2 https://www.gigabyte.com/us/Motherboard/GA-A320M-S2H-rev-20#kf

Rev 3 https://www.gigabyte.com/us/Motherboard/GA-A320M-S2H-rev-3x#kf

You have BIOS version: F51c dated: 07/02/2020. There's a newer BIOS available, based on which revision motherboard you have. See above links.

Comment: Done (except for the memtest86 step). I suspect it isn't the memory as I had exactly the same problem with my previous ubuntu machine which I stupidly threw away thinking it must be a hardware problem.  I have no idea why it says 13G. That is odd as you say.

Comment: @Anush Your memory may be installed incorrectly. Wait for the update to my answer.

Comment: I am trying the PC with the new settings (I guess the only real difference is the swap size). I also just asked a friend who has 16GB of swap and swapiness of 60 on a 8 GB RAM machine. Those are quite different numbers to me.

Comment: @Anush 8G RAM with a 16G swap is excessive swap. vm.swappiness=60 may need to go to 80.

Comment: I have 10 currently for swappiness. Should I increase it?

Comment: @Anush leave vm.swappiness=10 for now. Try the larger swap, and run the memtest. Report back.

Comment: I will do. It may be in 20 hours from now. Thank you so much for all your help so far.

Comment: @Anush See Update #2 in my answer.

Comment: `dmidecode -t` unhelpfully says  Manufacturer: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd.
 Product Name: A320M-S2H V2-CF
 Version: x.x . Maybe V2 contains the information?

Comment: @Anush If I had to guess, I'd say you probably have a Rev 1 motherboard. Closely examine the motherboard and locate the model # info imprinted on the motherboard, and the Rev number should also be right there. Any more problems since the /swapfile increase? Have you run memtest yet?

Comment: I ran memtest86 with no errors. It hasn't crashed again yet! I will report back in a few days. It would be amazing if changing the swap from 2GB to 4GB makes all the difference.

Comment: @Anush Great news! If the system stays stable, please remember to accept my answer by clicking on the checkmark icon that appears just to the left of my answer. Thanks!

Comment: It really does seem to have completely stopped hanging! Thank you so much. What a weird problem though.

Comment: @Anush Did you also do the BIOS update?

Comment: @Anush Last question... do you have a discrete video card plugged into a PCI slot?

Comment: No it's built in.  It's this thing https://www.amd.com/en/products/apu/amd-ryzen-5-3400g . Please ask as many questions as you need!

Comment: I didn't update the BIOS

Comment: @Anush I still have a hard time believing that 3G, of your 16G RAM, is being allocated to the video card. Maybe the BIOS update would help with that.

Comment: @Anush If it was me, I'd remove one DIMM, and then see if it reports 5G RAM. Then I'd switch out to the other DIMM, and see if it also reports 5G RAM.

Comment: @Anush I might also consider setting vm.swappiness back to 60.