# Ubuntu 20.04 freezes when changing the background image

Tags: bug-reporting, macbook-pro

what is the best way to deal with a frozen GUI?

I'm not able to change the bg image without freezing and am wondering if there is another option aside from reboot and try again.

Comment: Please clarify your OS & release, you've mentioned Lubuntu via tag so is it LXQt? but mention only Ubuntu in the heading (so is it GNOME?)     What I'd do would vary on what you're using.. but I'd likely switch to a text terminal & explore what's wrong... before I decided what to do... my last resort would be a SysRq reboot and never using the power key...

Comment: Sorry about the tag I fixed it. 
I didn't realise it works itself out until an Ai told me to be more patient. This future stuff is weird but I love it. The more I use the OS the better it runs. Thank you for the response. Ive also tried the ALT and arrow keys to try to shift my view to something else but it was completely frozen. 

What does seem to help is opening a terminal like you suggested, or at least trying to and then waiting. Sometimes it freezes completely and other times i have access to the mouse but nothing else. So far seems to be better.

It is Ubuntu 20.04 LTS amd 64x.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/1329657/249441